# How would a snake-tailed being cover their cloaca?

Tags: fantasy-races, clothing, snake

How could a creature (such as a lamia) with a long 'tail' similar to the rear of a snake, cover its cloaca without the covering slipping off or being too uncomfortable for everyday use?

Comment: Humans cover their genitalia (which are rather sensitive !) pretty much all the time.  We come in a bewildering range of sizes and shapes.  I'm not sure I see any real issue here that a tailor or garment designer would not address in your world in a manner that was specific to the garment and "person".  And I'm not sure why you need such a detail for WB purposes - e.g. what reader needs this level of detail ?

Comment: Humans come in a wide range of shapes and sizes, but only one structure, around which all human clothing is designed. A serpentine race would have a different structure, around which their clothes would be designed

Comment: That is the point.  Without knowing what their structure was in detail and exactly how sensitive and to what there is no way to answer your question.  I'm not inclined to think a lamia-like creature poses any issue - they'll hardly evolve into creatures who drag the most sensitive part of their bodies along the ground (unless it evolves with a natural cover that retracts when required), so it's likely somewhere in the part that is not in normal contact with the ground, which means it's just e.g. a padded part of clothing secured by elastic.  I do not see an issue.

Comment: it *wouldn't* cover it's cloaca. Because (1) the cloaca is an *internal* structure (which is already covered by muscles, skin and scales), and (2) the cloacal *opening* is normally closed shut and hardly visible. Reptiles do not have external genitalia. Have children stopped catching and handling lizards? ("Cover the cloaca" in a reptile would correspond with "cover the urinary bladder" in a human.)

Comment: These beings may still want to cover the opening, in the same way that we like to cover our mostly already covered anus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention if your creature has upper limbs or not.

If it has no upper limbs, the only option seems to be to have a sort of sleeve with something clingy on their body, either by using a belt in an area not in contact with the ground or by using elastic fabric that fits snug.

If they have upper limbs, on top of the solutions mentioned above they can user something similar to suspenders arranged around their upper limbs.

Answer (score 5):

Not necessary: because a cloaca is mostly hidden by scales. However if your story requires the use of some type of clothing, think along the lines of a Chinese finger trap: something that in normal use would tightly cling to the body, but by removing in the opposite direction of slithering would be generally easy.